# Closure of set $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $E:=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{R}$. I argued that $E^\circ$ does not exist because there does not exist an open set $V\subset E$ since $E$ consists entirely of separated points (singletons), which are all closed subsets of $E$.

However, I'm in doubt: could we say that the interior of $E$ is the empty set?

Also, is it correct to say that, since we can find a $B_\varepsilon(1/n)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ about any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $B_\varepsilon(1/n)\cap E\ne \emptyset$ and $B_\varepsilon(1/n)\cap E^c\ne \emptyset$, $∂E=E$?

And, finally, if the interior of $E$ does not exist, then the closure of $E$ does not exist either?

Comment: How could the closure of $E$ be the empty set?  It must contain at the very least $E$ itself (as a subset).  It also happens to contain $0$, the lone limit point that does not lie within $E$.

Comment: The interior *always exists*, and now it is the empty set.

Comment: And yes, the interior of $E$ is the empty set.  Thus $\partial E = E \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: @Berci: do you find my argument about the interior correct (except the conclusion)?

Comment: @BrianTung: How is the point $0$ included in the closure? (We haven't studied the concept of limit points yet).

Comment: Stop with this "doesn't exist" stuff. $\emptyset$ exists. $0\in cl(E)$ because... Archimedes. Given any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $n$ s.t. $1/n<\varepsilon$, so $B_{\varepsilon}(0)\cap E \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: If you haven't studied limit points yet, then what is your definition of closure?

Comment: @Prospect: $\bar{E}:=\bigcap\{B:E\subseteq B \text{ and } B \text{ is closed in } \mathbb{R}^n\}$

Comment: Well, you might as well talk about limit points then, because in the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}$, a set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points. How else would you think about closed sets?

Comment: @sequence: Without mentioning limit points explicitly, we can say that for any $\varepsilon > 0, B_\varepsilon(0)$ includes points of both $E$ (for instance, it must contain the point $1/\lceil1/\varepsilon \rceil \in E$), and $E^c$ ($0$ itself).

Comment: @BrianTung: Why must $B_\varepsilon(0)$ contain $1/\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil$?

Comment: Because the distance between $0$ and $1/\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil$ is $1/\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil \leq 1/(1/\varepsilon) = \varepsilon$.  I guess that only works for closed balls, so replace that with $1/(\lceil1/\varepsilon \rceil+1)$ and the argument holds.

Comment: How did you get from $1/\varepsilon < 1$ (correct) to $\lceil 1/\varepsilon \rceil = 2$ (not generally correct)?

Comment: No, $1/\varepsilon$ must be *greater* than $1$ because $\varepsilon < 1$.

Comment: What analysis text are you using?  Seems, in my opinion, simply making things too hard.  It works... but it is very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the definition of the interior of a set $S$ is the set of all points for which you can find an open ball around them fully contained in $S$. You are right to point out here that no such points exist, but just as the interior of the empty set $\emptyset$ and of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the empty set, so it is for your $E$.

In terms of your second question, a common definition of $\partial E$ is $\overline{E} \setminus E^o$, or the closure minus the interior. Since the interior is the empty set here, $\partial E = \overline{E}$. However, $\overline E \not= E$ since $0$ is a limit point for $E$ which is not contained in the set. Thus $0 \in \overline{E}$ but $0 \not\in E$.

$0 \in \overline{E}$ because we can define the closure of $E$ as the union of $E$ and of all its limit points. A limit point $p$ of $E$ is defined as a point for which $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists s \in E$ for which $s \in B_\epsilon(p)$ and $s \not= p$. This intuitively means that for something to be a limit point, it has to be arbitrarily close to elements of the set $E$.

Comment: What is $s$ in this case? I haven't conceived of your definition of a limit point yet. Been trying to imagine the situation but I don't know what $s$ should "look" like.

Comment: $s$ depends on $\epsilon$ (and $p$, but in this case $p=0$). For example, if $\epsilon=0.01$, then $s=1/101$ would work since $1/101\in E$ and $1/101\in B_{0.01}(0)$.

Comment: I think you're lacking $s\neq p$ in the definition of a limit point.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You're right, I'll modify the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The interior of $E$ = {interior points of $E$} = $\emptyset$.  It exists.  It's just empty.

In your third paragraph:  You have a mistake in your definition of $\partial E$.

For a point $x$ if for *every* $\epsilon > 0$, $(B_{\epsilon}(x)-\{x\}) \cap E \ne \emptyset$ and $(B_{\epsilon}(x)-\{x\}) \cap E^c$ then $x$ is a point of $\partial E$.  But NOTE you have to exclude the point $x$ itself.  $x$ will always be in $E$ or it will be in $E^c$ so one of those two conditions will *always* be true.  So we are only considering points *other* than x.

So for every $1/n$ we *can* find $0 < \epsilon < 1/n - 1/(n+1)$ where $(B_{\epsilon}(x)-\{x\}) \cap E = \emptyset$. so $1/n \not \in \partial E$.

So what points *outside* E are in $\partial E$?  Well, either $0$ jumps out at you or it doesn't.  For all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $1/n$ such that $0< 1/n < \epsilon$ so $0$ is a limit point of E.  It's easy to show this is the point in $\partial E$.

So $\partial E = \{0\}$ and $\overline E = \partial E + E = E \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry, we have not studied limit points yet, so I don't follow. For your question about my third paragraph, I was using a definition of the boundary from my Analysis book.

Comment: I'll modify my answer.